# Creating a data type from a Name?

Tags: haskell, template-haskell

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Local variables in Template Haskell declarations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5722523/local-variables-in-template-haskell-declarations)

I'm trying to construct a simple Template Haskell function that, given a string like "Foo", will construct the syntax tree for `data Foo = Foo`.

Right now, I'm trying to do something like `mkDecl name = [d|data $(conT name) = Foo|]`, but that's giving me the error: "Malformed head of type or class declaration: $(conT name)". Any idea what's going on?

I could just write it out using dataD and such, but I prefer this way since it'd be much clearer what's going on.

Comment: I don't understand your syntax. You can't use `data` inside a function. Also you can't put a pattern/function inside a list like that.

Comment: I'm using Template Haskell, which lets you write Haskell code that outputs Haskell code.

Comment: Ah, okay. So you're using Template Haskell. Might want to mention that in your question :P